# Selenium IDE: Clearing a text field

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to know how to clear a text field in Selenium IDE.

I have tried the sendKeys command with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.clear()`?

Comment: What is normally in the text field?  How do you clear it manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use "type" and for the value leave blank.

```
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>id=someID</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that using 'Type' and then a space worked.

Comment: I did not need to use a space.

Answer (score 0):

send key with${KEY_SHIFT}${KEY_HOME}${KEY_SHIFT}${KEY_DELETE} works